# ngRoute doesnt work with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ngroute

I m trying to use ngRoute with typescript. When i run the page it doesnt show the template. It doesnt also give any Error. I checked the template url, it is there as it supposed to. Any ideas why i dont get any page on the browser ?

```
///<reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="tlob.d.ts"/>


     module tlob {

            export class Route {
                constructor(module:angular.IModule) {
                    if (console) {
                        console.log('module.route initializing...');
                    }

                    module.requires.push('mgcrea.ngStrap'); // register AngularStrap


                    angular.module('tlob.route', ['ngRoute']) // create new Angular Module
                        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider: angular.route.IRouteProvider) {
                            $routeProvider.otherwise('/');

                            $routeProvider
                                .when('/', {
                                    templateUrl: 'ts/page1/page1.html'
                                })

                        }]);


                    module.requires.push('tlob.route'); // add Angular Module to dependencies
                    module.requires.push('ngRoute');

                    if (console) {
                        console.log('module initialized');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE

```
module tlob {
    export class tlob {

        private module:angular.IModule = null;

        constructor() {
            if (console) {
                console.log('module tlob initializing...');
            }

            this.module = angular.module('tlob', ['ngSanitize']);
            this.module.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                console.log('TestController initialized');
            }]);
            new Configuration(this.module); // setup configuration e.g. Logging
            new Route(this.module); // setup routes
            if (console) {
                console.log('module tlob initialized');
            }
        }

        static getModule():angular.IModule {
            return angular.module('tlob');
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: did you check the browser dev tools to see if the http request points to the correct file?

Comment: yeah, so stragely there is no http request for the html

Comment: Could you share how this class is initialized?

Comment: sure its under update

Comment: uhm.. the code in the constructor of a class will only run if you call new ClassName..  I have the feeling that something like that is missing. :) You can try debugging the code to be sure. :)